# How can I refer to a model variable in a Field Calculator or Pyculator formula?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, sextante

I am new to QGIS 2.0.1 Modeler (Sextante) and not very able in Python programming.

My question regard the use of field calculator (or advanced python field calculator) inside the modeler.
**Is it possible to refer in the field calculator formula to an input variable of the sextante model?**

Example for Buffer:
In the graphical modeler I define 2 model inputs:

1. *layer* = the point layer to be buffered (type: vector layer)
2. *buff_dist* = the buffer radius (type: number)

I use the "Fixed distance buffer" algorithm, setting `"Imput Layer" = *layer*` and `"Distance" = *buff_dist*`. It creates a temporary output shapefile.
I want to add a new numeric field in the output of the "buffer" algorithm, with value equal to the buffer distance previously defined (*buff_dist*).

How can I refer to the variable *buff_dist* in the Formula (or Global Expression) of the "Field Calculator" (or "Advanced Pyculator") algorithm??

Comment: I have the same issue and didn't understand the fixed/implementation solution.
How did you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

I've added a feature request in Sextante's feature/bug tracker. Maybe someone there can come up with an alternative way of doing this:

http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8743

Comment: I added another comment there: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/8743#note-6