# How to multiply a user-defined input parameter with a field value within the graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-modeler

I have the same Question as asked in this post ([How to connect input parameter to the field calculator algorithm within the graphical modeler?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164937/how-to-connect-input-parameter-to-the-field-calculator-algorithm-within-the-grap)) and the answer from [Joseph](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25814/joseph) already helped a lot:

```
##Update field by number=name
##Layer=vector
##Fields=Field Layer
##Number=number 0

from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

num = str(Number)
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Fields)
e = QgsExpression(num + '* 5')    # Change value to suit your needs
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```

Anyway, I'm looking for a way to multiply the number that the user enters in the interface with the value of the chosen field. In the script provided in the answer, the field value is ignored and the user value gets multiplied with the number defined in the script (default 5).

I have to admit that I'm not that much of a python programmer, so any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Miron, the code you linked to contained a mistake in which all features recorded the same output value (i.e. user input `num` multipled by `5`). I've edited that post =)

Comment: Huh, I just realised with the edited post in the question you linked to, you could just change `##Number=number 0` to `##Number=Field Layer` and the rest of the script can stay exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I would like to stick with the case where the user can choose a number to multiply it with the field values.
But if I try the modified code from the original post with `##Number=number 0` , the output gives NULL as filed values.

Comment: Apologies but I can't seem to reproduce your error. Are you using the exact same code in your post? I noticed the `for` loop requires indentation (although this should force an error), I also tested this for strings, integers and real numbers so not sure where the problem is...

Comment: Hm, I'm using this code:

`##Update field by number=name
##Layer=vector
##Fields=Field Layer
##Number=number 0

from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer) 
layer.startEditing()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Fields)
n = str(Number)
i = str(Fields)
e = QgsExpression(n + '*' + i)
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()`

and it gives me NULL values in the table field

Comment: Could you share your shapefile on a public server or create a new shapefile, add some attributes, test the script and if it still comes out as NULL values then upload this shapefile please? Or perhaps someone else can confirm this behavour :)

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right, I created a new feature and an integer column and the script works like a charm. I have no idea why it would not work on my original feature witch is as well integer....anyway, thanks a lot for your help, really appreciated!!! cheers, Miron

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked for you...eventually =)

Comment: Just for the record: I figured the reason the script does not work was the the field name contained a "-" in the name (risk-class). If I change the name into "risk_class", the script works fine ;) very strange indeed

Comment: Brilliant that you pinpointed the cause, thank you! Yes, I wouldn't have thought that would impact the features, will have to keep this in mind in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the following script which multiples one field by the other. The output is saved in whatever field you selected for `Fields`:

```
##Update field by field=name
##Layer=vector
##Fields=Field Layer
##Number=Field Layer

from qgis.core import QgsExpression

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)  
layer.startEditing()

idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(Fields)
n = str(Number)
i = str(Fields)
e = QgsExpression(n + '*' + i)
e.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

for f in layer.getFeatures():
    f[idx] = e.evaluate(f)
    layer.updateFeature(f)

layer.commitChanges()
```