# QGIS adding numeric value to algorithm into modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, parameters

Aim:
i would like to create a model that allows my user to select records from a table between two years.
Methodology: 
i am using modeler in QGIS LTR 2.14.9 (win is the OS of my PC) table A is a vector file (point), select by expression is the algorithm which should run the following expression:
"date" >= start_year AND "date" <= end_year
where start and end year are two numbers.

I try to add to the model two parameters (numbers) called start_year and end_year with a min/max values 1800/2050

I would like to see these two parameters taken as input in the expression i wrote in the select by expression algorithm but i am not successful. 
I have checked on StackExchange and i came across this previous post:

[How to multiply a user-defined input parameter with a field value within the graphical modeler?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182695/how-to-multiply-a-user-defined-input-parameter-with-a-field-value-within-the-gra?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is creating a script still the only solution or there is another one for people without coding experience?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to my question but something i worked out, it is not the most elegant solution but it is working now. However, i am still looking for an answer to my original post.

The way i sorted my problem out is the following: i added a select by attribute algorithm which takes as input the vector file and as value the start_year (string). the algorithm performs the following date >= start_year.
Then i added a second select by attribute algorithm and this time the input is the previous selection and the parameter is end_year. The algorithm performs date <= end_year. NOTICE: it is important to save the first selection (date <= start_year) and then use this output as input for the second select by attribute algorithm. Otherwise the final result is wrong. I have tested again as i had noticed problems. The model looks like in the picture in attachment

[image]

As said, it is not elegant but it works. I am still interested in knowing if, a part from a script, there is another way to answer the original question i posed.