# Connecting number parameter to Field Calculator in QGIS Modeler

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I intend to develop a model with field calculator processing using the QGIS Modeler.

How do I include the number input by the user to be as a value in Formula of Field Calculator?

[image]

This is the model that I want to make, but I stuck in including number parameter into my next field calculator.

For additional information, below is the interface that I want to have.

[image]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If you have a solution, could you please add that?

Answer (score 6):

In Field Calculator window, you have to click  [image] button, select "Model Input" and select "Number Parameter" (in your case, `Coefficient`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mr. Kadir! but then how I fill the formula? I want to multiply the coefficient with one of the column from the input layer

Comment: is `Coefficient` a constant value or it will be entered bu user?

Comment: it will be entered by the user, then the value will be incorporated in the field calculator formula

Comment: I guess, you need to write a script for this. You pass Coefficient and field to the script, and it returns result of the multiplication. Then result goes to Field Calculator.

Comment: Solution for QGIS 2 (not working in QGIS 3) 1.[How to connect input parameter to the field calculator algorithm within the graphical modeler?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164937/how-to-connect-input-parameter-to-the-field-calculator-algorithm-within-the-grap) 2. [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164937/how-to-connect-input-parameter-to-the-field-calculator-algorithm-within-the-grap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72569/how-can-i-refer-to-a-model-variable-in-a-field-calculator-or-pyculator-formula)

Answer (score 4):

A pretty dirty solution to this is to use the "String concatenation" tool to generate an expression that you feed into the field calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you should be able to use it as a variable `@Coefficient`, (originally used inputname without whitespaces and an @ at first sign) e.g. `99 * @Coefficient + 123`, but in my experience this sometimes does not work using the processing tool field calculator in graphical model.

However, you can simply use **refactor fields** instead. It offers pretty much the same possibilities as you have with field calculator + some extra options by reorganizing fields or even adding multiple calculated fields at once. This tool will also list your available variables. Just setup your field and click on the expression button.

[image]